# How can I copy text from some site which disable right click, and also select text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, copy

How can I copy text from some site which disable right click, and also select text?
I mean I cant select any text from that site, and also I cant right click on that site.
Do I have to Inspect Element and Find that text?
or is there any easier way?

Comment: Life is unfair.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome or any of the popular modern browsers, open Developer Tools by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and then click on the magnifying glass icon (or equivalent icon in other browsers) to turn on inspect mode. Move to the content within the web page and point to the specific portion of text that you want to copy. The HTML code corresponding to the pointed area will appear in the docked Dev Tools window. Double click on the HTML code to copy the content you need.

Alternatively, you can save the page as a text file in Internet Explorer and then you can get just the text within the web page in the text file. In IE, choose File > Save As and in the dialog box that opens up, specify the Save as type as Text file.

**Also you could try the site after disabling JavaScript in your browser.**

Answer (score 0):

For doing so, you have several methods:

1. Disable JavaScript
2. Remove the event handler(s) (if you are a developer)
3. Use DOM

Answer (score 0):

You could use latest `Intenet Explorer`.

`Caret Browsing` is a new feature introduced in Internet Explorer 8 and later.  With this feature enabled, you can use the navigating keys on the keyboard, select text & move it around within a webpage .

You can select and copy snippets of text as short as a single character by using only the keyboard. Other content types such as tables or images can also be selected and copied.

**Enable Caret Browsing in Internet Explorer**

To turn on Caret Browsing in `Internet Explorer`, press `F7`.

[image]

It can be enabled on a per tab basis or for all tabs and windows. Moving the cursor within the text of a web page is like moving the cursor within the text of a Microsoft Word document. To select text, hold the Shift key & press the arrow keys.

Instead of  using a mouse to select text and move around within a webpage, you can use standard navigation keys on your keyboard : Home, End, Page Up, Page Down & the arrow keys. This feature  is named after the caret, or cursor, that appears when you edit a document.

Reference [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/caret-browsing-in-internet-explorer-8).